# Rails getter on primary_key issue on update record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Greetings fellow devs,

I'm having an issue regarding the use of getter on table's id (primary_key), I encountered update records not working as expected, I'm new to ruby, I've been searching for the same issue but couldn’t find one.

I created a method in MainController

```
def do_the_hash_thingy(id)
  return id + 10
end

def do_the_unhash_thingy(id)
  return id.to_i - 10
end
```

and this is the Model

```
def id
    if self[:id].present?
        MainController.new.do_the_hash_thingy(self[:id])
    end
end
```

Let say the id is 4, after the hash process, it should be 14, and return back to 4 after unhash process

```
SampleTable.find(MainController.new.do_the_unhash_thingy(params[:id]))
SampleTable.column1 = 'new data'
SampleTable.save
```

Log result

```
UPDATE `sample_table` SET `column1` = 'new data', `updated_at` = '2017-11-18 00:00:00' WHERE `sample_table`.`id` = 14
```

weird that it still update on id 14 instead of 4

I've check the value of hash and unhash are returns as expected

Ruby version: 2.4.1

Rails Version: 5.0.6

Comment: Are you sure `column1` is a class method?  `SampleTable.column1 = 'new data'`????

Comment: If you're passing id=4, then it will seach for -6 in the SampleTable. Can you  review your question and repost. thanks.

Comment: @imechemi at show route, I got 14 from id 4 from the table, and in update route, I pass the value 14, unhash it which is converted back to 4, and find the record to update it, you can see the log I included, it still update for the row 14 not 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved in rails 5.1.0. Please consider upgrading to 5.1.x.

Comment: thank you very much, I upgraded the version and it's working, phew, I thought that I'm missing steps